# Azure Logic App : how to scale azure logic app without using ISE (Integrated Service Environment)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, autoscaling

Here I want to know, how we can **trigger or execute 2000+ workflows of the logic app** with a **single click**?

I know an **ISE (Integrated Service Environment)** service provides a **scaling** facility for the same, but here I don't want ISE.

However, the **standard plan** provides the same thing for a single tenant, and using it we can trigger n num of workflows as per the plan we select. So is it possible to use a standard plan to trigger 2000+ workflows with a single click?

Moreover, Which plan is costly **ISE or Standard** for the **azure logic app?**

Answer (score 0):

> how we can trigger or execute 2000+ workflows of the logic app with a single click?

2000 is a really huge number of workflows to get triggered but one workaround is that you can use postman to create a collection and then add all the 2000 workflow URL requests in the collection and then run the whole collection.

[image]

> Moreover, Which plan is costly ISE or Standard for the azure logic app?

In general the Integration Service Environment

> |  | Developer | Premium |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Base Unit | $1.03 per hour | $6.64 per hour |
> | Scale Unit | N/A | $3.32 per hour |

and the Standard plan follows the below pricing

> |  | Price Per Call |
> | --- | --- |
> | Standard Connector | $0.000125 |
> | EnterpriseConnector | $0.001 |

I would say it all depends on what connectors, for how long, Memory, CPU.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Integration service environment (ISE) - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing#ise-pricing)
2. [Standard (single-tenant) - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing#standard-pricing)